# How to find an explicit equation for the inverse of an integral of a high degree polynomial with certain constraints?

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, inverse, inverse-function

I have a 6th degree polynomial function with decimal coefficients that I've rounded to make it easier:
$$ f(x) = -0.1227 x^6 + 0.0227 x^5 +0.5221 x^4-0.2252 x^3 -0.5113x^2+ 0.3047x +0.1176$$

this polynomial has roots at $x_1=  136.485 $ and $x_2 = 419.239$ and I need to find the inverse of:
$$ g(x) = \int_{x_1}^{x} f(x) dx$$
where $x1 \le x \le x2$

Because f(x) is positive over the interval, the integral is always increasing, which means the inverse would be a valid function.

I tried to take the derivative of a composition of functions:
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx}\left[g(g^{-1}(x)) = x\right]$$
$$ g'(g^{-1}(x))(g^{-1}(x)' = 1 $$
but I have no idea how I would proceed from there. I've also considered the easier solution in which I just solve for when $g(x)$ is equal to a specific value, but it would be vastly more computationally efficient if I could find a way to solve for an explicit equation for $g^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: $g\,$ is a polynomial of degree $\,7\,$. There is no closed form for the roots of the general septic, so no explicit form for $\,g^{-1}\,$ in general.

Comment: Even if a septic formula did exist, judging by how quickly the computation grows from linear to quadratic to cubic to quartic (the highest power for which a formula by radicals exists), it is likely that Newton's method would provide a sufficiently accurate value faster than such a septic formula.